# Sitecore Item with html attributes - Webforms

Tags: html, sitecore

I have this code origin in a layout:

```
<div class="pm-single-post-img-container" style="background-image:url(images/01.jpg);">
    <div class="pm-single-post-title full-width">
        <p>
        <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Title" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also i have a image field , and want to get image url set to div background , like this :

```
<%
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Image"];
var thumbnailUrl = string.Empty;
if (imageField != null && imageField.MediaItem!=null)
{
    thumbnailUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);
}
%>
<div class="pm-single-post-img-container" style="background-image:url(<%=thumbnailUrl%>);">
    <div class="pm-single-post-title full-width">
        <p>
            <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Title" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this way has error when the page in edit mode , because use block code.
If you have another solution for this case , please share for me . Thanks !

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Can you provide it?

Comment: Here : The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid to use code blocks.

Your page(aspx.cs) or control(ascx.cs) can have public property.

```
public string BackgroundUrl
{
    get
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Image"];
        var thumbnailUrl = string.Empty;
        if (imageField != null && imageField.MediaItem != null)
        {
            thumbnailUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem);
        }
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

And you can use it in your code

```
<div class="pm-single-post-img-container" style="background-image:url(<%=BackgroundUrl%>);">
    <div class="pm-single-post-title full-width">
        <p>
            <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Title" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you get this error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks" follow [Presentation Component Troubleshooting](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/presentationcomponenttroubleshooting-a4.pdf)

Added about Page Editor image editing after question in comments:

There is no way to do editing of background image of div in Sitecore out of the box. But you can render  tag instead of background image for PE mode. For example:

```
<sc:Image Field="Image" ID="ImagePE" runat="server" Visible="false">
<sc:Text runat="server" Field="Title" ID="TitlePE" Visible="false"/>
<div runat="server" ID="DivNormalMode">
 ... your current code
</div>
```

And control visibility by code behind

```
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
{
    ImagePE.Visible = true;
    TitlePE.Visible = true;
    DivNormalMode.Visible = false;
}
```

While changing markup and styles you can achieve pretty good appearance in PE mode and ability to edit image.

Or, if you have WYSIWYG requirements you should have [Sitecore Edit Frame for your image field](http://www.techaspect.com/blog/web-content-management/sitecore/sitecore-editframe-for-page-editor). You will be able to edit background image as field.

Comment: Thanks Anton, but with your solution and my solution, i can't modify image in Experience Editor .

Comment: @MrBac, it is another question :-)

Comment: @MrBac, I added description of two ways how you can extend your code with ability to edit image.

Comment: you right, another question :) . Thank you Anton, i get it .